# Getting high latency(>500ms) while reading/writing data to cloud fire store

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-firestore

My firestore collection has <100 documents, I am using firestore-go-SDK to establish connection. Below is the code
which I am using to query firestore.

```
    func connectFirestore() {
        ctx := context.Background()
    
        // Sets your Google Cloud Platform project ID.
        projectID := <Project-ID>
    
        client, err := firestore.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Failed to create client: " + err.Error())
        }
        defer client.Close()
    
        iter := client.Collection("User").Documents(gg)
        startTime := time.Now()
        _, err = iter.Next()

        endTime := time.Now()
        log.Println("Latency of DB call ", endTime.Sub(startTime))
    
    }
```

When I try to access the same collection using a nodejs application I get a latency of less than 10ms. Code for nodeJS:

```
async function firebaseGetData() {
    const db = new Firestore({
        projectId: <Project-ID>,
        keyFilename: <Project-Key-File>,
    });
    firebaseGetData(db)
    var startTime = Date.now()
    const snapshot = await db.collection('User').get();
    var startTime = Date.now()
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
        var endTime = Date.now()
        var latency = endTime - startTime
        console.log("Latency " + latency)
    });
}
```

Comment: You are getting all docs in once query. So your end time should be after  `iter := client.Collection("User").Documents(ctx)`. The iteration is post DB call. Same with nodejs. So the point is may be the `log.Println(doc)` in go is taking time. To narrow down check that and update.

Comment: hey, even when I remove the `log.Println(doc)` it doesn't change anything. Actually, `iter := client.Collection("User").Documents(ctx)` is not taking alot of time but `iter.Next()` is taking majority of the time.

Comment: Removing a print won't fix anything. If you don't want to fetch all documents, you shouldn't loop over all documents You need to remove the `for` loop.

Comment: when I did this: https://play.golang.org/p/cUdw0I7KG2l

This is the output I got
2021/01/01 16:10:03 Request to ping service

2021/01/01 16:10:04 Latency of DB call  1.052424523s
2021/01/01 16:10:04 Latency of DB call  20.441µs


I have only one document in my collection and that's why only 2 print statements

Comment: Hey, there is something in here. It appears to me that the iter.next() is fetching data from stream using grpc. https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/master/firestore/query.go#L702

Comment: @Abhijit-K Thanks for the information, Can you suggest something which might help me to reduce the latency.

Comment: If that is so, in one way it is preventing to load lot of data at once.

Comment: Try `...Documents(gg).GetAll()` and let me know.

Comment: Posted in answer below with pros and cons

Comment: Hey sorry I had a mistake in measuring the latency for GetAll, I was only measuring the latency to parse. Even this doesn't give a better result. `GetAll` still gives latency ~750ms

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the problem, i am closing the client after every API request which forces golang to create new Firestore client for every request and Firestore does have cold start problem.

So, saving the already initialized client and reusing it solves the problem.